# Create a URL that expires and map it to an asset

Tags: php, node.js, apache, url

I have some files on my server and they are accessible publicly. I want to create a dynamic URL and map it to assets stored on my server. e.g path to asset on my server is /serverurl/images/image1.png.

I want to write a script to create dynamic random URL to access this asset that expires with time, lets say after 4 days. http://urlthatexpires.com/randomkey

I found few links but its for Amazon S3-

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/generate-expiring-amazon-s3-link/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you could do is have a database table that maps dynamic urls to assests.

E.g.

```
asset_maps

id | urlcode | asset | expire
1  | somerandomcode | /var/whatever/path/myfile.jpg | someunixtimestamp
```

Then if you have a php script, you can pass in the randomly generated code as a parameter, and fetch the asset.

e.g.

If you had the following DB record:

id: 2
urlcode: ABC123
asset: /var/stuff/file.zip
expire: 123456789

And let#s say your php file is called "file.php"

You would access it through: file.php?file=ABC123

Then in file.php you could use that query parameter to look up which asset to retrieve, and make sure it hasn't expired yet.

Then  you can use file_info to find out what kind of file that is and send the relevant headers to force a download of that asset.

--

You could then use .htaccess to format the url into something different, e.g.

http://f.yoursite.com/ABC123

Or whatever you want.

--

As far as actually generating the random codes, you could do something like:

```
function generate_random_string($length=10, $alphaNumericOnly=false)
{

$chars = " _?!@#~ 23456789 _?!@#~ AzBbCcDdEeFfGgHhJjKkMmNn _?!@#~ PpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz _?!@#~ 23456789 _?!@#~ ";

if ($alphaNumericOnly){
    $chars = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/i", "", $chars);
}

$l = strlen($chars) - 1;

$output = "";
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{

    $r = mt_rand(0, $l);
    $output .= $chars[$r];

}

return $output;

}
```